# Find the mean based on similar other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking for a way to find the mean of numerical values based on a certain column. I looked to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824278/pandas-how-to-find-mean-of-a-column-based-on-duplicate-rows-in-another-column) for advice but it requires all values of one column to be the same and I'm sure there's a Pythonic way that would do that for all values that are duplicates.

Here's an example.

```
data = {
  "Name": ["John", "John", "Robert", "Robert", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Sarah", "Sarah"],
  "Score": [84, 45, 67, 87, 88, 100, 76, 91]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image]

I'd like it so there's one row of John with whatever the mean of John is. Same with Robert, Cindy and Sarah.

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).mean()`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your awesome responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# groupby and mean
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Score'].mean()
```

```
Name    Score
0   Cindy   94.0
1   John    64.5
2   Robert  77.0
3   Sarah   83.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg({'Score': pd.Series.mean})
```

```
     Name  Score
0   Cindy   94.0
1    John   64.5
2  Robert   77.0
3   Sarah   83.5
```